# create and associate multiple arrays to variable without string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, implicit-conversion

I have been looking around but could not find the solution to my problem.
It seems my arrays are being converted to string when associating them with a variable.

My question is:
How to create "small" arrays within a foreach loop without having the resulting array being converted to string. Then how can I inject those newly created arrays inside another "big" array to expect a result like so:

**expected $big variable output**

```
[["apple", 8, "leeloo"], ["chery", 0, "leeloo"],]
```

**current $big variable output**

```
[apple, 8, 'leeloo'],[banana, 0, 'leeloo'],
```

**current PHP code**

```
<?php

    $inputs = array(
        "apple" => 8,
        "banana" => 0
    );

    // transform inputs keys/values into arrays ("$small")
    // inject those arrays into a new array ("$big")
    $small = '';
    $big = '';
    foreach($inputs as $key => $value){
        $small .= "[$key, $value, 'leeloo'],";
    }
    $big = array($small);

    echo "small type: ", gettype($small); // string
    echo "small output: ", $small; // [apple, 8, 'leeloo'],[banana, 0, 'leeloo'],

    echo "big type: ", gettype($big); // array
    echo "big output: ", implode($big); // [apple, 8, 'leeloo'],[banana, 0, 'leeloo'],
    // expected output: [["apple", 8, "leeloo"], ["chery", 0, "leeloo"],]   

?>
```

ulitmately, my goal is to have my $big variable behave like this:

```
$big = [
    ["apple", 8, "leeloo"],
    ["banana", 0, "leeloo"],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are creating a string `[apple, 8, 'leeloo'],[banana, 0, 'leeloo'],` with array like structures.

When you cast it to an array, the type will be array but with a single entry which will be that assembled string. Running implode on that array will give you back the string.

I might be easier to set your `$big` variable to an empty array.

In the loop create a new array with your values and add that array to `$big`

```
$inputs = array(
    "apple" => 8,
    "banana" => 0
);
$big = [];
foreach($inputs as $key => $value){
    $big[] = [$key, $value, 'leeloo'];
}

print_r($big);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => 8
            [2] => leeloo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => banana
            [1] => 0
            [2] => leeloo
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/XT4uF)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm ! Interesting way to set up arrays, appreciate the time you took to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $inputs = [
        "apple" => 8 ,
        "banana" => 0
    ];

    $big = []; // empty array

    foreach ($inputs as $name => $number) {
        $big[] = [$name,$number,'leeloo'];
    }

    $big = json_encode($big);
    echo $big;
    // expected output : [["apple",8,"leeloo"],["banana",0,"leeloo"]]
```